# Force file download for specific folder using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to force all files that are found in a specific folder to open the download dialog window when access via their direct URL.

Example url: domain.com/wp-content/uploads/folder-name/folder-name/

If i have to set specific file types that is fine too, I mostly need PDF, JPG and PNG files to force the download window.

I have tried adding the below to the .htaccess folder and none have worked:

```
<Location "/wp-content/uploads/folder-name/folder-name/">
    <Files *.*>
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </Files>
</Location>
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public_html/wp-content/uploads/folder-name/folder-name/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ".+\..+" "-" [T=application/octet-stream,L]
```

I have also tried putting just the below directly into the folders own .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .png .jpg .pdf
```

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpg|pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? I should mention this is a folder inside a WordPress instance, so not sure if this requires special settings?